# React error: Too many re-renders, when i try to conditonally render using a button

Tags: reactjs

This happens when i try to conditonally render using a button, what should i do?

This is the main function:

```
    const hi = () => 
    {
        if (qajo)
        {
            return (
                <>
                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-dark">Email</a>
                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-dark">Phone</a>
                </>
            )
        }
    }
```

This is the main return:

```
return (
  <>
    <a href="#" className="btn btn-dark" onClick={() => setQajo(true)}>Request a quote</a>

    {hi}
  </>
)
```

I have a useState variable at the start, called qajo:

```
    const [qajo, setQajo] = useState()

    setQajo(false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call setQajo state of component change and React try to recreate them.. but when component is recreated setQajo change state again.. never ending loop. Set initial state in this way:

```js
const [ qajo, setQajo ] = useState(false)
```